Android: Configuration with name not found - Multiple flavors implementation
I'm trying to implement dependencies only for a specific build variant.
I have 4 flavors split in 2 dimensions as follows:
flavorDimensions += listOf(
    ProjectAndroidConstants.APP_TYPE_DIMENSION,
    ProjectAndroidConstants.OPERATING_SYSTEM_DIMENSION
)


productFlavors {
    // 'operatingSystem' dimension
    create(ProjectAndroidConstants.ANDROID_FLAVOR) {
        isDefault = true
        dimension = ProjectAndroidConstants.OPERATING_SYSTEM_DIMENSION
    }

    create(ProjectAndroidConstants.HUAWEI_FLAVOR) {
        dimension = ProjectAndroidConstants.OPERATING_SYSTEM_DIMENSION
    }

    // 'appType' dimension
    create(ProjectAndroidConstants.TOTO_FLAVOR) {
        isDefault = true
        dimension = ProjectAndroidConstants.APP_TYPE_DIMENSION
    }

    create(ProjectAndroidConstants.TATA_FLAVOR) {
        dimension = ProjectAndroidConstants.APP_TYPE_DIMENSION
    }
}

The problem is a single flavor implementation works but not a combinaison:
// This works
"${ProjectAndroidConstants.TOTO_FLAVOR}Implementation("com.myproject.android:authentication-session:0.1.0")


// This doesn't work and I get error: Configuration with name 'totoAndroidImplementation' not found
    "${ProjectAndroidConstants.TOTO_FLAVOR}${ProjectAndroidConstants.ANDROID_FLAVOR}Implementation"("com.myproject.android:authentication-session:0.1.0")

On this page there is an example of Implementation but with only one dimension and when there is multiple dimensions there is no Implementation example.
I precise that work with Kotlin DSL
EDIT: I have took care of the camel case in my constant already. But since I already got 2 answers focusing on my concatenation instead of the real problem, I'm making clear that here is one of my variant:

So we can see totoAndroid variant
And this hardcoded string instead of using my concatenation:
"totoAndroidImplementation("com.swissquote.android:authentication-session:0.1.0")

Does not work
We can effectively see that the configuration totoAndroid same as variant, is not found.


If you open up the menu in Android Studio and click Build > Select Build Variant..., and then click the Active Build Variant list for your app module, which variants do you have in the list? Have you tried using the exact same word order and capitalization as in that list?

I'm using the exact same wording totoAndroid or even tried totoAndroidDebug (+ implementation)
I also tried with a groovy build.gradle so the implementation is suggested (so no wording error) and I get the same error...

According to the documentation, this is supposed to work with two dimensions.
Combine multiple product flavors with flavor dimensions

The second part of this string likely just isn't properly capitalized.
Concatenating ${...}${...} defintely won't result in camel-case.

${ProjectAndroidConstants.TOTO_FLAVOR}${ProjectAndroidConstants.ANDROID_FLAVOR}Implementation

These important seeming ProjectAndroidConstants make everything unreadable.And not sure if this would result in totoAndroidImplementation (not found) or maybe androidTotoImplementation? This should be by the order of flavorDimensions.
Assuming the string may be correct, it might still may require the corresponding sourceSets. productFlavors generate the variants, but one needs sourceSets to declare dependencies.
sourceSets {
    create("totoAndroid") {
        java.srcDirs("src/main/kotlin", "src/totoAndroid/kotlin")
    }
}

Then it should be able to add the dependency:
totoAndroidImplementation("com.myproject.android:authentication-session:0.1.0")

Which is not the same as the likely incorrectly concatenated: totoandroidImplementation.

The concatenation was not the problem. As I have edited my original post showing it.
However the sourceSets fixed the problem. Why do I need to define a sourcesets when declaring dependencies for multiple flavors combination but not if we only have 1 flavor such as toto/tata from app_type dimension ?

If you also could edit your answer to highlight the sourceSets part as this was the issue and removing the concatenation part or make it less important so future users will be focused on the sourceSets part and so I will give you the bounty :)

When you work with multiple flavor dimensions in Android, the Gradle plugin creates configrations for each combination of the product flavors. These configurations are named by concatenating the flavor names in the order of the flavor dimnsions, followed by the build type and the dependency type (Implementation, Api, etc.).
Given setup that was created by you, with appType and operatingSystem as flavor dimensions, the correct cofigration name would conctenate the flavors from each dimension in the order they are listed.
For example, if you have:
toto from the appType dimension
android from the operatingSystem dimension
The corresponding configuration for the implementation would be:
totoAndroidImplementation("com.myproject.android:authentication-session:0.1.0")
But, since you wrote that ${ProjectAndroidConstants.TOTO_FLAVOR}${ProjectAndroidConstants.ANDROID_FLAVOR}Implementation isn't working, it's likely that the concatenation is not generating the correct configurtion name, or there's an issue with how the dimensions are being ordered or referenced.
Solution
Check Flavor Naming: Ensure that ProjectAndroidConstants.TOTO_FLAVOR and ProjectAndroidConstants.ANDROID_FLAVOR are defined correctly and contain the expected values. For example:
object ProjectAndroidConstants {
    const val TOTO_FLAVOR = "toto"
    const val ANDROID_FLAVOR = "android"
}```
Concatenate Correctly: Instead of using `${ProjectAndroidConstants.TOTO_FLAVOR}${ProjectAndroid


I have said in the comments that I also tried concatenating without accssing the constants. Plus Constants is always safer than hardcoded strings. Doesn't work anyway.
